# Is Riemann's R-function $R(x)$ differentiable?

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

**Edit note:** I mis-wrote the expression originally, resulting in helpful-but-incorrect feedback. The function is now correctly expressed.

I suspect that the answer to this is a resounding 'no', but I'm curious...

Is there a way to differentiate Riemann's approximation to the prime counting function

$$R(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\text{li}(x^{1/n})$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Moebius function, and $\text{li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral?

Note that $R(x)$ can also be expressed as

$$R(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\bigr(\log(x)\bigl)^k}{k! k\zeta(k+1)}$$

I am aware that there are differentiable *approximations* to $R(x)$. My question is whether the function itself can be differentiated.

Comment: For a start, why not move the $\operatorname{li}(x)$ factor out of the sum that doesn't otherwise seem to depend on $x$?

Comment: Hi @Henning Makholm, could you please clarify? For example, look at the explicit expansion of the function I noted below the original definition...

Comment: x @Richard: Write $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}n \operatorname{li}(x) =  \operatorname{li}(x) \sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}n$. The sum does not depend on $x$, and the derivative of the logarithmic integral is (obviously) $\frac1{\log x}$, so you get the derivative $\frac1{\log x} \sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}n$.

Comment: Hi @Henning. You were writing your explanation as I was writing mine! Could you maybe have a quick look at my update? I wish the latest software update on this site would allow graphics uploads... Tried several different ways... It's very obvious visually.

Comment: x @Richard: Are you sure you have the correct expression for $R(x)$, then?

Comment: Your first formula should read
$$R(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\text{li}(x^{1/n})$$

Comment: Just this moment spotted that! Many apologies! OP now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last formula,  you can easily prove that $R$ is infinitely differentiable. since its is normaly convergent for the $\mathscr C^p$ norm on every compact $[a,b]\subset ]0,+\infty[$: 
$$ \left\| \frac{\log^k(x)}{k! k \zeta(k+1)} \right\|_{\mathscr C^p} \leq \frac{\max(|\log(a)|,|\log(b)|)^k}{k!}$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\max(|\log(a)|,|\log(b)|)^k}{k!} = \exp(\max(|\log(a)|,|\log(b)|))-1 < +\infty $$

Comment: Thank you @Can I play with Mathness. Yes, differentiable *in principle* in the range of positive reals (as you could see from its curve, and as you have rigorously established)... But what is the actual derivative...? (I should add that some of the notation you just used is a bit beyond me. My A level was a very long time ago!)